# Prove that the gradient of $f$ is $0$ at a point

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, functions

> Let $f \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^2, \mathbb{R})$, and $D$ be the closed disk of radius $1$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Now suppose that for all $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \backslash D, f (x,y) = -x^2+y^2$.
>
> Prove that there is a point $a \in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that : $\nabla f(a) = 0$

So I need to prove that that : $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} (a) = 0$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} (a) = 0$. First outside of $D$ this is never possible since in order to have $-2x =0$ and $2y = 0$ we need $(x,y) = 0 \in D$.

Thus the point at which the gradient is $0$ is necessarily in $D$. Now somehow the fact that $f$ is equal to $-x^2+y^2$ outisde of $D$ should have consequences on the value of $f$ on $D$. I think this is due to the fact that $f$ is $C^{\infty}$. Moreover I think that it only have consequences on $\partial D$, that's why I am quite shure that the point $a$ is on the frontiere $\partial D$.
But from here I don't see how to continue...

Thank you !

Comment: Note that $f$ is harmonic on $\mathbb{R}^2-D(0,1)$. Are you aware of the (tons) of consequences of this property?

Comment: @JustDroppedIn Oh I completely missed that ! I know what an harmonic function is but I don't know what are the properties such functions have. Actually I know that when a function is harmonic on the circle then $f(0) = 1/(2\pi) \int_0^{2\pi} f(e^{i \theta}) d\theta$ but since here it's only harmonic outisde the circle I don't know it it can help

Comment: Reminds me of the degree theory!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am terribly sorry for my previous answer. We focused on harmonicity so much that I thought $f$ was harmonic everywhere. No, it does not have to be equal to $-x^2+y^2$ everywhere just by that. This would be true if $f$ was harmonic in the disk too.

Anyway, a valid solution is the following: take a compact set containing the unit disk properly, e.g. the disk of center $0$ and radius $2$.  Now $f$ attains its max and min values there, so it suffices to prove that this happens in the interior of our set. Then, this point will be a local extremum of $f$ on the whole plane and therefore critical, i.e. of zero gradient.
But this is simple: on the boundary of our set, it is $f(x, y)=-x^2+y^2$ so no point can be a minimum: if $x>0 / x<0 $ take the point $(x\pm h, y)$  for some small $h>0$ that obviously attains a lesser value than $(x, y) $. Similarly,no point of the boundary can be a maximum.

Notice also that the critical point must lie in the interior of the unit disk, as you observed.

Comment: Thank you but How does it help in showing that there is a point where the gradient of $f$ is $0$ ? The fact that $f(0)$ is $0$ doesn't mean that the gradient of $f$ is $0$ at $0$ right ?

Comment: Woops. Lost track of the problem, let me edit it.

Comment: Thank you. Wow this is quite amazing that it forces $f$ to be equal to $-x^2+y^2$ on the whole plane. Unfortunately I don't know complex analysis, is there a way to show this using only real analysis ? Because to me you demonstration work because $D$ is closed. So $R^2-D$ is open and hence there is a sequence in $R^2-D$ which converges to a point on $\partial D$, whereas if $D$ was the open disk it's a completely different story since we can't find a sequence in $R^2-D$ which converges to a point on $\partial D$ right ? thus $f$ is not necessarily $-x²+y^2$ on $\partial D$

Comment: But you did not consider the boundary bounder at radius 2, did you? You cannot move $x$ outside your domain and say hey you do not have a minimizer. or am I missing something?

Comment: @BehnamEsmayli i cannot understand your comment

Comment: Ok, let us be precise: I agree that max and min of f restricted to B(0,2) -- closed ball -- exist. I also see why this does not occur on $\partial B(0,1)$. I also agree that it cannot occur on the annulus $1<|p|<2$. But why can it not be attained on $\partial B(0,2)$? It can happen that min of $f|_{B(0,2)}$ occurs on boundary $\partial B(0,2)$ while it may fail to be a min for $f|_{R^2}$.

Comment: @BehnamEsmayli because as I say, on the circle of radius 2 we have $f=-x^2+y^2$, so we can find points near it and inside the closed disk that attain greater/smaller values.

Comment: I see for most point now.  But how do you rule out, say, (o,2), not being a max for $f|_{B(0,2)}$? No matter how you move inside the disk, you y will drop and -x^2 will drop. Sorry, I am not attacking your solution, just honestly trying to understand. Because it is an interesting question.

Comment: @BehnamEsmayli i guess you are right about this,i didn't see it.